# How to encode/decode ASN.1 streams with OpenSSL?

Tags: c, openssl, asn.1

I need an API to encode/decode an ASN.1 stream.  I've read that OpenSSL supports this in C and I have access to it in my project, though I don't know how to actually use these functions.  I effectively need to decode a struct, a SEQUENCE.  Can anyone recommend how to do so?

Comment: I think its a good question and you got my upvote, but I also think it might be off-topic for the site since you don't have related code (or the place where you are having trouble in the code). This is a place where I wish the site would relax its requirements....

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265656/decoding-asn-1-messages-using-openssl-asn1parse-tool

Answer (score 0):

It [looks like](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/asn1parse.html) openssl can be used to generate ASN.1 encodings of data through a cumbersome command line interface. It's not really an API that you could use - you'd be having to create one yourself that, underneath, made a lot of system calls like `system("openssl asn1parse -genstr 'UTF8:Hello World'")`. That sounds like a lot of work.

You're far better off using a proper ASN.1 toolset, take a look at the [tools page](http://www.itu.int/en/ITU-T/asn1/Pages/Tools.aspx) on the ITU's website.